# RequestException.php line 71

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to make request to Facebook API and pass facebook_access_token to check if this token is vaild or not. I am using Laravel and guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0 package to send the request as below:

```
public function fbLogin(Request $request)
{
  try {
     $fb_token = $request->input('accessToken');
     $client = new Client();

     $fb_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token_info?access_token='.$fb_token; 
     $res = $client->get('$fb_url');
     return response()->Json(['data' => $res->getBody()->getContents()],200);
     }catch (Exception $e) {
     //catch Exception
     }
}
```

when I call this function from Postman I get this "***ClientException in RequestException.php line 71: [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request***"
but when I hit the same URL with the same access token I got the response from Facebook API, so any body can help in me in this issue?

Comment: Is the endpoint `/oauth/access_token_info` documented anywhere? Couldn't find anything on it, so I suspect it might be outdated. Anyway, the up-to-date way to do this is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

First of all, switch to Guzzle 6.x. [As you can see](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle#version-guidance), 4.x is not supported long time already.

Then, fix error in your request:

```
 $client->get('$fb_url');
```

There should be just `$fb_url` (without quotes).